# The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Sometime my web application is working and some time not working.

Whats the reason of this exception and solution.

```
The specified network name is no longer available.

Exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified network name is no longer available
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and finding out which part of your code is throwing this exception? Is your web app trying to connect to a database, or some other resource that's on the network?

Comment: Yes there is a problem in a query if I add a condition in a query "WHERE [City] IS NULL" then this error occurs. @DipraG